# What is the largest value you can store in a custom field (as meta data for a post)?

Tags: custom-field

What is the largest value you can store in a custom field (in the meta data value for a post type)?

Comment: I hope I didn't misunderstand what you mean by "largest value"?

Comment: That's correct I've updated the question.

Comment: It's helpful to describe what you're doing - do you mean the biggest number, or perhaps the longest piece of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meta *value* is a `LONGTEXT` field which can store about 4 GB (gigabytes) of characters (non-binary), but I can't help you test the limit and note that the number of characters that can be stored will depend on the *character encoding*.

A quote from *MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual*:

***Note:** The four TEXT (data) types are `TINYTEXT`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, and `LONGTEXT`.*

> `VARCHAR`, `VARBINARY`, and the BLOB and TEXT types are
> variable-length types. For each, the storage requirements depend on
> these factors:
>
> - The actual length of the column value
> - The column's maximum possible length
> - The character set used for the column, because some character sets contain multibyte characters
>
> For example, a `VARCHAR(255)` column can hold a string with a maximum
> length of 255 characters. Assuming that the column uses the `latin1`
> character set (one byte per character), the actual storage required is
> the length of the string (*`L`*), plus one byte to record the length
> of the string. For the string `'abcd'`, *`L`* is 4 and the storage
> requirement is five bytes. If the same column is instead declared to
> use the `ucs2` double-byte character set, the storage requirement is
> 10 bytes: The length of `'abcd'` is eight bytes and the column
> requires two bytes to store lengths because the maximum length is
> greater than 255 (up to 510 bytes).

Another quote from the same manual:

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type,
> but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and
> server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of
> the communications buffers. ... You may also want to compare the
> packet sizes and the size of the data objects you are storing with the
> storage requirements, see Section 11.7, “Data Type Storage
> Requirements”

And actually, the question is more about MySQL/database than WordPress-specific API/function, so Stack Overflow is a better place to get further insights on the largest possible column value for `LONGTEXT`.

However, just in case it helps, storing a huge number/integer should not be an issue since it's treated as a string in the database, so for example inserting a `PHP_INT_MAX` value (which was `9223372036854775807` in my case) worked just fine for me:

```php
add_post_meta( 1, 'foo', PHP_INT_MAX );
$value = get_post_meta( 1, 'foo', true ); // 9223372036854775807
var_dump( PHP_INT_MAX === (int) $value ); // true
```

**References:**

- [*Database Description » Table: wp_postmeta* on Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta)
- [*TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT maximum storage sizes* on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13932750)
- [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual » 11.7 Data Type Storage Requirements » String Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)
- [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual » 11.3.4 The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

### Additional Details

( I initially thought you're asking mainly about the meta *key* (i.e. name), so I included the following from my original answer. )

The meta *key* is limited to at most 255 characters (`VARCHAR`) and if more than that, (in my case) the meta data is not added/saved, regardless in PHP/WordPress (e.g. using `add_post_meta()`) or a direct SQL command (e.g. via phpMyAdmin).

**Sample test case** (on WordPress 5.4.2 and MariaDB 10.1 with strict mode *not enabled*):

```php
// Only the *first* metadata gets added.

$id = add_post_meta( 1, wp_generate_password( 255, false ), 'test' );  // meta key = 255 chars
$id2 = add_post_meta( 1, wp_generate_password( 256, false ), 'test' ); // meta key = 256 chars
var_dump( $id, $id2 ); // int(<meta ID>), bool(false)
```

Comment: Based on the info in your link, LONGTEXT is about 4 GB.

Comment: Yes, and I've revised the answer. I hope that's more helpful. :)